# Smooth Scrolling & Dynamically Changing the Page Title

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, title, marquee

I currently have a site that changes the title of the page to reflect whatever song is currently being played. What I would like to do is have the title of the page constantly scrolling so the user can see the full name of the song playing, even if they have a lot of tabs open.

I tried out a few different scrolling plugins, but the one I've found to work best is the plugin found here:
http://www.seangw.com/wordpress/index.php/2009/01/basic-ajax-tutorial-smooth-scrolling-text-marquee-with-a-jquery-plugin/

I can get the plugin working fine on a regular body element, but it doesn't work when I put it on the title of a page. I've tried wrapping the  tag in the  tags but it doesn't work. In addition, the title of my page changes dynamically, so the scrolling text would need to change as well.

Here is the javascript function where I am changing the title:

```
function playNext(newState)
{
    //alert("new state: " + newState);
    //unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5)
    if(newState == 0) //song is done
    {
        //**************minimize myself*******************
        var i = ' . $this->i .';
        var dataString = getDataString(i);
        minimizeSong(dataString, i);
        //**************maximize next song****************
        dataString = getDataString(i+1); //i + 1 is next song
        maximizeSong(dataString, i+1);
        //I will automatically start playing on load
    }
    else if(newState == 1) // if its playing, change the title
    {
        $("title").text("' . $this->title . ' by ' . $this->artist . '    - T3k.no");
    }
    else if(newState == 2) //song is paused, go back to original title
    {
        $("title").text("Paused - T3k.no");
    }
    else if(newState == 3) //song is buffering, change title
    {
        $("title").text("Loading '.$this->artist .' - T3k.no");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? How can I go about achieving this?

This doesn't work:

```
<html><head>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2"
      height="75" width="150">
    <title>WANT THIS TO SCROLL</title>
</marquee>
</head></html>
```

But something like this works fine:

```
<body>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2"
          height="75" width="150">
          <p>This is a test of a Smooth Marquee using jquery.</p>
     </marquee>
</body>
```

Comment: The code you posted has almost nothing to do with your marquee problem.  Making it almost impossible to answer your question.  Please post some code relative to the actual implementation of the marquee effect.

Comment: Edited my code to with examples of what works and what doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put this is your jQuery ready function:

```
(function titleMarquee() {
 document.title = document.title.substring(1)+document.title.substring(0,1);
setTimeout(titleMarquee, 200);
})();
```

The marquee plugin doesn't work as you expect it to because for one the **head** tag doesn't render. It's primary use is setting up your page and it's resources. The **marquee** tag is made for rendered page elements.  The **head** and **title** tags aren't in the "normal flow" as it were.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this helped a lot. It changes with my dynamically changing title. Some problems I still encounter though are: 1. After the title is done scrolling the first time, all the spaces are removed from subsequent marquees. 2. The scrolling isn't as smooth as the plugin I was using.

Comment: You can make a it a bit smoother by lowering the delay on the timeout function.  However, note that the browser throttles resources allocated to an inactive tab.  So a user could still end up seeing it as choppy at some point.  This really more of a browser hack as you can see from looking at the code.  You should be able to to solve the spacing problem with some more advanced string manipulation.  That said this is not best practice and would advise against putting this into production.